# Ubuntu 15.04 installation xboxdrv error with xboxdrv.service

Tags: software-installation, error-handling, xbox-360

I have repeatedly tried to install on Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit drivers for controller xbox360 and always got the same error after performing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/ubuntu-xboxdrv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-xboxdrv
...

Configuring the ubuntu-xboxdrv package (20150319-1) ...
/usr/bin/update-desktop-database
Failed to start xboxdrv.service: Unit xboxdrv.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
dpkg: error processing ubuntu-xboxdrv (--configure) package:
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error code 6
Configuring the evtest package (1: 1.32-1) ...
Configuring the joystick package (1: 1.4.7-2) ...
Parsing libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) triggers ...
Processing ureadahead (0.100.0-19) triggers ...
Processing dbus packet triggers (1.8.12-1ubuntu5) ...
There were errors while processing:
  ubuntu-xboxdrv
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This is a Grandfather question from 2005 and has a score of 3. Leave open.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (after the above installation attempt - when the install fails). It solved the same issue I had while installing ubuntu-xboxdrv:

1. Go to https://github.com/raelgc/ubuntu_xboxdrv/tree/master/src/lib/systemd/system, right click on xboxdrv.service and select "save linked content as" or "save target as" and save it as "xboxdrv.service" in an easily accessible path.
2. Open a terminal and navigate to the above path where xboxdrv.service is and run the following command :

   `sudo systemctl enable xboxdrv.service`
3. Then run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-xboxdrv` again.

This should solve the problem.

**Credit:** https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units